# Как сверстать подобный блок без bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

[image: Блок]

Я не особо понимаю как мне сверстать этот блок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding-inline: 10%;
}

.apps {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.apps img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 100vh;
}

.apps h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="info">
    <h1>How to use</h1>
    <p>Apps were originally intended for productivity assistance such as email, calendar, and contact databases</p>
  </div>
  <div class="apps">
    <div>
      <img class="icon" src alt>
      <h1>Download</h1>
      <p>Benefit from zero server maintenance, seamless collaboration and automatic</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="icon" src alt>
      <h1>Install App</h1>
      <p>Save test and local files directly on your machine with no cloud-footprint</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img class="icon" src alt>
      <h1>Ready to use</h1>
      <p>In the Japanese language pronunciation or reading of a kanji character</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```